# How to change a button from non-favorite to favorite in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am consuming an API and I want to know how you can change the state of a button that is inside * NgFor, the problem is that when I click to change the state from favorite to non-favorite, it changes them all as only the state can change one's? and if possible maintain the state of let's say favorite
When the user clicked it, I have tried it in several ways but I could not

Service

```
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ServiceService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  private url = 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/';

  getAllApi(){
    return this.http.get(`${this.url}/character`)
  }

  paginacion(paginacion:number){
    return this.http.get(`${this.url}/character/?page=${paginacion}`)
  }

}
```

home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ServiceService } from 'src/app/services/service.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  Personajes: any[] = []
  NuevosPersonajes: any[] = []
  public suma = 1;
  public status = false;

  constructor(private apiService: ServiceService) {
    this.allApi()
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  allApi() {
    this.apiService.getAllApi()
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
        this.Personajes = data.results;
        console.log(data)
      })
  }


  nextApi(paginacion: number) {

    this.suma = this.suma + 1;
    console.log(this.suma)

    this.apiService.paginacion(this.suma)
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
        this.NuevosPersonajes = data.results
        console.log(data)
      })
  }

  statusFav(status:boolean){
    this.status = status
  }

}
```

html

```
<div class="container mt-5">

    <button (click)="nextApi(1)" class="btn btn-outline-dark m-2">Next</button>


    <div class="card-columns" *ngIf="suma < 2; else elseBlock">
        <div class="card text-center" *ngFor="let personaje of Personajes">
            <img class="card-img-top" [src]="personaje.image" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">{{personaje.name}}</h5>
                <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional
                    content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            </div>
            <button (click)="statusFav(false)" *ngIf="status; else elseFav" class="btn btn-success btn-block"><i class="far fa-star"></i> Favorite</button>

            <ng-template #elseFav>
                <button (click)="statusFav(true)" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-block"><i class="fas fa-star"></i> Favorite</button>
            </ng-template>

        </div>
    </div>

    <ng-template #elseBlock>
        <div class="card-columns">
            <div class="card text-center" *ngFor="let nuevoPersonaje of NuevosPersonajes">
                <img class="card-img-top" [src]="nuevoPersonaje.image" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">{{nuevoPersonaje.name}}</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to
                        additional
                        content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ng-template>



</div>
```

thanks to the one who can help me.

Comment: Are you trying to get only one of your buttons  at a time to be in state "true"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `this.status` is not tied to any particular item, that's a component wide state. You need to have a `status` property that changes when you click favourite button.

Here stackblitz [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-spellf)

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using a class level status variable to save the favourite status for a user, add a status key on the each user object in the Personajes array.

allApi function below elaborates how to add a status property on each user object.

```
private allApi() {
    this.apiService.getAllApi()
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
        this.Personajes = data.results.map ( user => {
           if ( user && typeof user === 'object') {
               user['status'] = true;
           }
           return user;
        });
        console.log(data)
      })
  }
```

statusFav function toggles between the user status i.e. set it true if it was false initially and vice versa.

```
  public statusFav (user:any) {
    user.status = !user.status
  }
```

You can also use the value of user.status in an ngClass directive to toggle between 'far' and 'fas' classes instead of repeating the button code with an ngIf and ngElse condition

```
<div class="card-columns" *ngIf="suma < 2; else elseBlock">
        <div class="card text-center" *ngFor="let personaje of Personajes">
            <img class="card-img-top" [src]="personaje.image" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">{{personaje.name}}</h5>
                <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional
                    content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            </div>
            <button (click)="statusFav(user.status)" 
                    class="btn btn-success btn-block"> 
                   <i *ngIf="user.status" [ngClass]="{'fas' :user.status, 'far': !user.status}" class="fa-star"></i> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```